# Activar un checkbox dependiendo del valor de un input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy tratando de activar un checkbox dependiendo del valor de un input, lo he intentado con JQuery y con JavaScript pero nada me ha funcionado. El procedimiento es el siguiente:

1. Obtengo la fecha actual
2. El usuario pone una fecha por medio de un calendario
3. Calculo la cantidad de dias que hay
4. Debo activar el checkbox si la cantidad de dias es menor a 15

Todo me funciona hasta que debe activar el checkbox, por favor me ayudan, muchas gracias.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var now = new Date();
            var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var today = (day) + "/" + (month) + "/" + now.getFullYear();
            document.getElementById("fecha").value = today;
        });
    </script>
    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/img/core/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#desde").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showButtonPanel: false,
                showAnim: "show",
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                showOn: "both",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImage: "/img/datepicker.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                autoSize: true,
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: new Date(2050, 12, 31),
                yearRange: "1990:2050",
                monthNamesShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mayo', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
                monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
                dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lu', 'Mar', 'Miér', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mié', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sáb'],
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
                prevText: "Anterior",
                nextText: "Siguiente"
            });
        });
    </script>
    
     <script>
        function diasCalendario() {
            var fechaInicial = document.getElementById("fecha").value.split("/");
            var fechaFinal = document.getElementById("desde").value.split("/");

            var newFechaInicial = new Date(fechaInicial[2], fechaInicial[1] - 1, fechaInicial[0]);
            var newFechaFinal = new Date(fechaFinal[2], fechaFinal[1] - 1, fechaFinal[0]);
            var dias = newFechaFinal.getTime() - newFechaInicial.getTime();

            var cont = Math.round(dias / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1;
            document.getElementById('dias').value = cont;
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function activar() {
            var dias = document.getElementById("_1_1_31_1").value;
            if (dias < 15) {
                document.getElementById("_1_1_31_1").checked = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```html
<form>
<label>Fecha de radicación: </label> <br>
<INPUT CLASS="form-control" TYPE="text" NAME="fecha" ID="fecha" VALUE="" readonly>

<label>Desde:</label> <br>
<INPUT CLASS=" form-control" TYPE="text" NAME="desde" TITLE="Desde" ID="desde" VALUE="" onChange="diasCalendario();"
    readonly>

<label> dias_solicitud:</label> <br>

<INPUT CLASS="form-control" TYPE="text" NAME="dias" ID="dias" VALUE="" ONCHANGE="diasCalendario(); activar();" readonly>
    <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="checkbx" ID="checkbx" value="" onchange="activar();">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba esto, está simplificado pero responde a tu problema principal

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const check = document.getElementById("check");

input.addEventListener("change", updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  var fechaActual = new Date().getTime();
  var fechaIngresada = new Date(e.target.value).getTime();
  var diff = fechaActual - fechaIngresada;
  //convierto milisegundos a dias
  if (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) < 15) {
    console.log("LA DIFERENCIA ES MENOR A 15 DIAS");
    check.click(); //CHECK CHECKBOX
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="date" type="date" />
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" />
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda me funciono perfecto :)